# VertxUnitRunner with spring DI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vert.x

I am using Vertx With Spring.
When writing test cases, we have to use `VertxUnitRunner` as stated [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/). How use spring DI in the test cases written with VertxUnitRunner.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring-test version 4.2 and newer, you can do the following

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(/*load needed classes for Integration test here*/)
public class MyServiceTest {
  @ClassRule
  public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE= new SpringClassRule();
  @Rule
  public final SpringMethodRule  springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

  /* tests */ 
}
```

For additional information, [this link](http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2015/12/use-spring-test-without-setting-runner.html) shows how to load Spring context in tests without @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)